# Does time pass normally in the Enchanted Forest?

Tags: once-upon-a-time

After the first Dark Curse, and everyone returns to the Enchanted Forest, we meet Robin Hood, who has taken up residence in the Dark One's Castle. He has a young son named Roland, whose mother is Marian.

Neither character ever appeared in Storybrooke before, and Robin has no idea about Neal or anything else going on, backing up the idea that he wasn't just another random townie in Storybrooke. (Additionally, [the OUaT wiki lists them as only coming to Storybrooke with the second curse](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Storybrooke), for whatever that's worth).

But we later learn that

> Marian died before the first Dark Curse was cast, having been sentenced to death by Regina herself.

Additionally, we meet Mulan was not taken to Storybrooke by the curse, and who appears to be the same age after the Dark Curse is broken as when

> she met Belle, prior to the curse.

**Why have these characters not aged in all this time?** Time was frozen in Storybrooke, but the Enchanted Forest was not supposed to have been affected in the same way.

Comment: Someone else may have a better explanation,  but I've always gotten the impression that the writers are more interested in telling stories about the way these characters are all connected than they are in making consistent rules for the world to operate on.

Comment: I kinda remember Mulan saying, in the beginning of Season 2, that everyone was frozen in time in the Enchanted Forest while the curse was on. I'm not sure so I'm not posting that as an answer.

Comment: @GeorgeT that would definitely explain it, if anyone can find confirmation of it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by George T in the comments, the remaining people in the enchanted forest did get frozen during the first curse. And it was later discovered that it was Cora who froze them with her. So all of the remaining inhabitants of the enchanted forest didn't get old because of it.

From [onceuponatime.wikia.com](http://onceuponatime.wikia.com/wiki/Cora) :

> Cora informs Hook that they will both be frozen for the next
>   twenty-eight years until the savior breaks the curse and frees them.
>   When the time comes, she plans to go to Regina in her greatest moment
>   of need.